# atom editor unable to install packages - Windows

Tags: atom-editor

When I try and use the Atom package manager I get the following error:

`spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Python27\Scripts ENOENT`

And am unable to install any packages.  I have tried uninstalling and deleting all associated files and reinstalling, but the error does not change.  I have also changed my Path variable. I have atom installed on my other laptop and it works fine.
I've tried searching online and have commented here: https://github.com/atom/settings-view/issues/514#issuecomment-110322065 but can't find any indication as to what the problem is.
I'm using 64-bit Windows 7.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Running atom as an administrator fixed a similar issue for me